# SSIS Sharepoint Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

Im trying to pull data from a sharepoint list into SQL Server and I am having issues.  Currently, I'm running SSDT 2015 Version 14 and we are running SharePoint 2013.  We are using the adapters from here:

https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples/releases

The drivers say they install, but they don't show up in the SSIS toolbox.  Running this task on a Windows 8 computer remotely, it runs fine (currently only way pull SP data).  When I try it in windows 10, it fails for various reasons (right now its saying metadata for SP list source cant be upgraded).  I tried manually installing the connection and adapters, and they now show up in windows 10, but I get the upgrade error.  I see a lot of posts telling me to get adapters from codeplex, but I cant seem to figure out how to install the files I get, and I am opposed to using the third party adapters from cozyroc, kingswaysoft, etc as those cost ~$1000 for a yearly subscription. Ive also tried using the OData source, but the sharepoint data it gets isnt right.

If anyone could shed some light on this topic it'd be much appreciated.  This is one of the last parts of the project not yet working.

Comment: Shouldn't you post that as an issue to that repo? It looks like it's a clone of the SSIS community samples that someone modified for his own use.

Comment: Check [Reading SharePoint Lists with Integration Services 2017](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1733/reading-sharepoint-lists-with-integration-services-2017/). It shows how you can use the OData adapters that are maintained and even included in SSIS itself in SSIS 2016, 2017